# Using constants across files in the same package

Tags: perl, package, constants

I keep production code separate from test code in two separate files with the same `package`. This may be a bit shady, but it's been working well because I avoid the hassle of exporting and importing subroutines.

I've hit a problem using `constant`

#### example.pl

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package A;

1;

use constant WORLD => "WORLD\n";

sub helloWorld {
   print STDERR "Hello, World\n";
}

sub helloAll {
   print STDERR "Hello, All\n";
}
```

#### test.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package A;

use lib '.';
require 'example.pl';

helloWorld();
helloAll();
print "Hello, ", A->WORLD;
```

#### output

```
./test.pl
Hello, World
Hello, All
Hello, WORLD
```

This all looks good, but if I try to refer to the constant as `WORLD` or  `A::WORLD` instead of `A->WORLD` I get an error.

> Bareword "A::WORLD" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./test.pl line 13.

I'd like to understand why, since constants are subroutines in essence, and the rest of the subroutines work fine.

Comment: *"I avoid the hassle of exporting and importing subroutines"* It's not so difficult, and you really should get used to doing this "properly". Your `example.pl` should be a *module*: `Example.pm` in both your production and test environments with `package Example` at the top. You need to add `use Exporter 'import'` and you must create lists of exported symbols into `our @EXPORT` (by default) and `our @EXPORT_OK` (by request). And that's all. Apart from being common practice, it also documents your module better as you can differentiate between public and private symbols easily.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I do use modules extensively. I find the OP scheme convenient during development and testing, because my programs are mostly long calculations, split in small subroutines, and I want to test every little thing (especially those that will never be public). The best orthodox way I have found is by using test tags in `Exporter`, but in general this scheme seems to work well for me (and file scoping also helps protect many things.) . However, I do appreciate your comment and I especially admired how you laid out a full introduction to modules using just a few sentences.

Answer (score 5):

[require](http://p3rl.org/require) happens in runtime, so the constants are not known in compile time. Wrap the require in a BEGIN block:

```
BEGIN { require 'example.pl' }
```

**BUT**: you should use modules and include them with [use](http://p3rl.org/use), not require scripts. Your usage of `package A` shows you aren't familiar with [perlmod](http://p3rl.org/perlmod) and [Exporter](http://p3rl.org/Exporter), so read the documentation and try to understand it and apply it to your work.

Comment: I would like to add that the `1;` in example should be placed at the end of the file

Comment: Thank you, this actually worked. Any idea why referring to WORLD as method works while as plain old constant / subroutine does not?

Comment: The only problem is when you use the sub as a bareword (that doesn't apply to constants only). The parser needs to know how to interpret the bareword. `WORLD()` will "work", too, but it doesn't constant-fold the constant.

Comment: Thank you for this final clarification, it made it all clear for me, especially when `print "Hello, ", &A::World;` worked great.

Comment: Using the `&` also prevents constant folding, though.

Comment: Yes, exactly the same way as WORLD() would, I understand that, but it helped with my understanding with why A->WORLD worked when A::WORLD did not. Your original answer had already covered 95% of my question's scope, but I appreciate your further clarifications that helped me understand even better.